# Правописание и употребление числительных

Tags: части-речи

(напишите словами)
1. с 2794365(Т.п)
2. о 24978001
3. над 431023
4. по 4001981
5. к 2222674
6. через 5799797
7. между 200621
8. за 100625034(Т.п)
9. из-за 495667
10. ради 720055
11. от 9999999
12. для 4341987
13. с 777777777
14. несмотря на 84486
15. вместе с 888666

(образуйте прилаг., порядков. числит.)
 1. 40%
 2. 197 кг
 3. 474 м
 4. 8 млрд
 5. 4385 млн
 6. 798 тыс.
 7. 99 м
 8. 401 млн
 9. 118 млн
 10. 303 млн
 11. 764 млрд
 12. 700 лет
 13. 377 литров
 14. 1 1/2 процента
 15. четверть(финал)

Comment: Это только в цирке могут! )))
Разве что : полуторапроцентный раствор, сорокапроцентный кредит (?!) восьмимиллиардный житель, семисотлетний дуб, четвертьфинальный матч, девяностодевятиметровый мост, стодевяностосемикилограммовый баран... Остальные примеры - чистая фантастика.

Comment: >Это только в цирке могут!  
  
И в банке. Даже в бухгалтерии.

Comment: Резко сомневаюсь в финансовых работниках! Не потянут, ни боже ж мой...

Comment: ну смотря что. Насчет порядковых - может быть. А вообще склонение числительных приходится знать.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. с 2794365 с двумя миллионами семьюстами девяноста четырьмя тысячами тремястами шестьюдесятью пятью 2. о 24978001-о двадцати четырёх миллионах девятистах семидесяти восьми тысячах одном (одной)3. над 431023 -над четырьмястами тридцатью одной тысячей двадцатью тремя 4. по 4001981 по четырём миллионам одной тысяче девятистам восьмидесяти одному (одной)5. к 2222674-к двум миллионам двумстам двадцати двум тысячам шестистам семидесяти четырём 6. через 5799797-через пять миллионов семьсот девяносто девять тысяч семьсот девяносто семь 7. между 200621-между двумястами тысячами шестьюстами двадцатью одним (одной) 8. за 100625034(Т.п) -за ста миллионами шестьюстами двадцатью пятью тысячами тридцатью четырьмя 9. из-за 495667 -из-за четырёхсот девяноста пяти тысяч шестисот шестидесяти семи 10. ради 720055 -ради семисот двадцати тысяч пятидесяти пяти 11. от 9999999 -от девяти миллионов девятисот девяноста девяти тысяч девятисот девяноста девяти12. для 4341987-для четырёх миллионов трёхсот сорока одной тысячи девятисот восьмидесяти семи 13. с 777777777-с семьюстами семьюдесятью семью миллионами семьюстами семьюдесятью семью тысячами  семьюстами семьюдесятью семью   14. несмотря на 84486 -несмотря на восемьдесят четыре тысячи четыреста восемьдесят шесть 15. вместе с 888666- вместе с восьмьюстами (восемьюстами)восьмьюдесятью( восемьюдесятью) восемью (восьмью)тысячами шестьюстами шестьюдесятью шестью
2. 40% сорокапроцентный 2. 197 кг-стодевяностосемикилограммовый  3. 474 м-четырехсотсемидесятичетырёхметровый 4. 8 млрд- восьмимиллиардный5. 4385 млн -четырёхтысячтрёхсотвосьмидесятипятимиллионный6. 798 тыс.-семисотдевяностовосьмитысячный 7. 99 м-девяностодевятиметровый 8. 401 млн -четырёхсотодномиллионный9. 118 млн-стовосемнадцатимиллионный 10. 303 млн трёхсоттрёхмиллионный11. 764 млрд семисотшестидесятичетырёхмиллиардный12. 700 лет -семисотлетний 13. 377 литров-трёхсотсемидесятисемилитровый 14. 1 1/2 процента -полуторапроцентный 15. четверть(финал)- четвертьфинальный

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Успехов в изучении такой трудной темы!

Comment: А ведь современные программы это делают без проблем.

>8. 401 млн -четырёхсотодномиллионный...  
  
Гм Никогда не задумывался, что это за форма "одно".  

а если 401000001-й - четырестаодинмиллионпервый? )))

Comment: Вы о каких программах? Подскажите.

Comment: >а если 401000001-й - четырестаодинмиллионпервый?)))

@behemothus, по идее, ещё "смешнее" - *четырёхсотодномиллионнопервый*.

Comment: насчёт "одно": http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-009.htm - i6487
Примечание 2. Числительные один, тысяча, миллион, миллиард соединяются со второй частью слова с помощью соединительных гласных о и е , т.е. они функционируют как существительные:однодневный, двадцатиодноведерный, тысячелетие, двадцатипятитысячелетие, миллионоголосый, миллиардофутовый. - http://www.xenoid.ru/materials/russkiy/uch_rus_morph05.php :тридцатиодномиллиардный.

Comment: 3. Над 431023 -над четырьмястами тридцатью одной тысячей двадцатЬЮ тремя.

Comment: Да, конечно, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: >Вы о каких программах? Подскажите.  
  
Да их масса. Хотя бы 1с.  
Если кому нужна, могу и сам написать за пару дней максимум, как только будет время и условия. Только дайте точную грамматику, а то я в "четырёхсотодномиллионнопервый." (©Марк Из) крепко сомневаюсь на фоне "шестьдесят первый" или "тысячапервый". 

>Примечание 2. Числительные один...  
  
Одно - не один. Я именно про форму без И. И это не связано напрямую с темой образования порядковых. 
Однодневный (ср. единообразный)
Двухдневный
Тысячедневный
Миллионодневный